# How to trigger click event in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a js file with the following code to fire a `click` event. But the event is not working. The console given just above for `jQuery.fn` gives the result. 
In my HTML I have a form with input values and a `submit` button with class `submit`.
Can anyone help?

```
(function(jQuery) {

    "use strict";
    console.log(jQuery.fn)

    jQuery(".submit").on('click',function(e){
        console.log('test')
        e.preventDefault();

    });

})(window.jQuery);

<form name="login-form">
    <input id="email" type="email">
    <input id="password" type="password">
    <input type="submit" class="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Show us your html code,else it might be hard to show you the error

Comment: click can be triggered by ```$("css-selector").click()``` function. In your case ```$(".submit").click()```

Comment: What does `console.log(jQuery(".submit").length);` give you?  Are you sure you have an element with class `submit` ?

Comment: Also, as @dorintufar comment shows, your question title and question text do not match - please update.

Comment: From close vote: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behaviour, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it** in the question itself.

Comment: You can use $("css-selector").trigger('click'); function.

Comment: @freedomn-m I have the `submit` class in the submit button

Comment: @HareeshSNair-i see too much comments but why you not posted your html code till now?Every one putting guess and giving answer

Comment: If you have a button such as `<button class='submit'>submit</button>` and *no other code* then what you have *will* work.  If you have some *other* code that gets fired first then it may be stopping your code.   If you have a submit input, `<input type='submit' class='submit'>submit</input>` then it will likely be submitting after your console log and the console clearing - change the browser to **not clear console on page refresh**.  All of these are **IF** - because there's no code to confirm and so your question got put on hold.

Comment: Updated: your button is `<input type="submit" class="submit" value="submit">` so your event fires on click, shows "test" in the console then the form submits and the console is cleared and you think it's not shown.  Change the console.log to `alert("test")` to block javascript.  Or change the button to `<input type="button" class="submit" value="submit">` (changed `type=`) so that it doesn't submit/refresh the page.  Or change the browser option so it doesn't clear on page refresh.

Comment: The number of comments/answers shows people want to help - adding the html 30 minutes ago would have got you an answer 30 minutes ago...

Comment: By the way https://jsfiddle.net/L67xye3f/1/ works just fine for me.

Comment: @freedomn-m The alert does not works in my case. It is not entering into the event function

Comment: Then you have other code not presented here.

Answer (score 1):

**`.submit`** is a `css-selector`.Make sure you have a **class** `submit` on you submit button.

**Here is working snippet:**

```js
(function(jQuery) {

    "use strict";
    //console.log(jQuery.fn)

    jQuery(".submit").on('click',function(e){
        console.log('test')
        e.preventDefault();

    });

})(window.jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" class="submit" value="Send Request">
```

Comment: Better be a big update as clarification has already been requested in the comments whether OP has a `<button class='submit'>` or whatever already.

Comment: @freedomn-m- where OP said this that he already has a **class='submit'** ?By my answer I just want to convey this.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen-I have updated my answer. hope it will justify to you as well.

Comment: @NullPointer that's my point, OP hasn't stated either way if (s)he has a class=submit - it's been **requested** to confirm the actual scenario.   See the first comment from Carsten and my first comment against the question.   Your answer *assumes* that it's missing, we asked for clarification if it's missing.

Comment: Ok I got it.i overlooked the comments and focused on question.May be my bad.Thanks.I will delete my answer in case.

Comment: There was also a comment to clarify the question as the text doesn't match the title :)  Otherwise a fine answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

```
$('body').click(function() {
  $('#submit').trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: I don't want to trigger it using jquery. I want to call the event function when i click on my button manually

Comment: @HareeshSNair TBH this is what your question *does* ask.  "trigger" is a specific term that means what this answer gives you - ie trigger the click.  The term you are looking for is "fire", "fire the event by clicking the element".  It sounds like you want the "event function to be called when you click the button".

Comment: OK. Yes that is what I want. Can you give me a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Hope so this will help you.

```
(function (jQuery) {
    jQuery('body').on('click', '.submit', function (e) {
        console.log('test')
        e.preventDefault();
    });
})(window.jQuery);
```